# How to remove auto complete duplicates?

Tags: php, forms, select, autocomplete

How do I remove the duplicates? I have 4 rows in my database table with all the same name, for example a brand, Apple, which is used 4 times, how do i remove the other duplicates with the same name? this is to avoid redundancy when inputing brands.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#prod_brand").autocomplete("prod_brand_auto_complete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
  });
 });
</script>
```

Here is the prod_brand_autocomplete.php

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET['q'];
 $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12148qx3er','buybranded') or die("Database Error");
 $sql="SELECT prod_brand FROM inventory WHERE prod_brand LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY prod_brand";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

 if($result)
 {
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo $row['prod_brand']."\n";
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing MySQL functions; they don't mix. `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: If by "remove" you mean to not fetch/show duplicates; use [`DISTINCT`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx).

Comment: where should i put the DISTINCT?

Comment: Do `SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2` etc. in your case `SELECT DISTINCT prod_brand FROM inventory`

Comment: You can also use `LIMIT 1` - Plus, don't forget to change this `mysql_real_escape_string` and add an `i` after the `l`, along with DB connection parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$my_data = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xxx', 'buybranded') or die("Database Error");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE prod_brand LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY prod_brand";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));    
if ($result) {
    $existBrand = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['prod_brand'] . "\n";
        if (in_array($row['prod_brand'], $existBrand)) {
            $delSql = "DELETE FROM buybranded.inventory WHERE id='$row[id]'";
            $delResult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $delSql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            continue;
        }
        $existBrand[] = $row['prod_brand'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some comments around this that explains your answer?

Comment: You're mixing a `mysql_*` based function `mysql_real_escape_string` with the rest of `mysqli_*` functions. Those two APIs do **not** mix.